# Отсечь лишние обьекты с массива

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть массив в котором находятся объекты.

```
 PortalApi.searchServices(data)
   .then(function(get) {
     $scope.services = response;
     $scope.checkFavorites(get);

     if(response.length < 12){
       $scope.services_new = false;
     }else{
       $scope.services_new = true;
     }
     $scope.preLoader = false;
})
```

В нём проверка по айди чтобы вывести только определенные значения, но в итоге выводятся еще и дубликаты. Думаю применить `.filter`, чтобы пройтись по `response` и убрать все объекты в которых свойство `isFavorite = false`.

Но когда пробую, то мне возвращает пустой массив:

```
PortalApi.searchServices(data)
  .then(function(get) {
    //allFavorites
    $scope.checkFavorites(get);

    // $scope.services = response;
    function filterByFav(service) {
    $scope.services = response.map(service => {
      if (service.isFavorite == true) {
        return true;
      }
    });
  }

  $scope.services = $scope.services.filter(filterByFav);

  // $filter('filter')(response, expression, comparator, anyPropertyKey);


  console.log($scope.services);//todo delete

  if(response.length < 12){
    $scope.services_new = false;
  }else{
    $scope.services_new = true;
  }
  $scope.preLoader = false;
})
```

Что не так или как сделать по-другому?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил:

```
 PortalApi.searchServices(data)
            .then(function(get) {
                //allFavorites
                $scope.checkFavorites(get);

                function isFavoritTrue(service) {
                    return service.isFavorite == true;
                }
                $scope.services = response.filter(isFavoritTrue);


                if(response.length < 12){
                  $scope.services_new = false;
                }else{
                    $scope.services_new = true;
                }
                $scope.preLoader = false;
            })
```

Comment: описывай в решении _как именно_ решил. И почему так заработало